# Is considered a bad practice to delete a tumbleweed question and ask again it at http://mathoverflow.net/?

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow, cross-posting

I earned the tumbleweed badge for this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424658/any-reference-to-an-algorithm-for-finding-the-largest-empty-circle-on-a-sphere and I was thinking to delete it from https://math.stackexchange.com/ and ask it at https://mathoverflow.net/

Is it considered, from the Community, a bad practice? I know that there are people with an account here at https://math.stackexchange.com/ and also at https://mathoverflow.net/ and I think that maybe it can be annoying to them to see a sort of "cross-posted" question.

What do you think?

Comment: I'd say it's not bad practice at all. In fact, we now have the power to migrate it over to MO, since they (finally) updated to the SE2 model. Would you like me/us to do that?

Comment: @mixedmath Thank you for your help! I would be happy if you can migrate the question for me... I just ask you to have a look at the question and tell me if is bad or need to be edited... I do not want to bother the people at MO with a bad question. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest to double check (before requesting migration) that the question would be appropriate in MO, otherwise it may just be closed there. One way to double check is to ask a question in meta: "Would this question be appropriate?" You state the question, maybe describe some of the history (posted here, no answers, ...), and further ask for improvements in case that would make it more acceptable.